# Create a SQL Developer procedure having a parameter and returning sum

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying a basic exercise in SQL Developer. What I want is returning the value of the sum from a column related to the client_id given by parameter.

My SQL code:

```
create or replace
    PROCEDURE autorizationCosts2016 (client_id IN NUMBER) IS
    DECLARE
      sum NUMBER(100);
    BEGIN 
      SELECT SUM(au.cost) INTO sum FROM autorization au, client cl 
      WHERE to_date(au.date_f, 'YYYY') = '2016' AND to_date(au.date_i, 'YYYY') = '2016' AND au.id_client = cl.id_user;
dbms_output.put_line('Sum: ' || sum);
    END autorizationCosts2016;
```

My problem is that I don't get how to compile the code.

My tables:

- `AUTORIZATION` (date_i, date_f, client_id, cost)
- `CLIENT` (user_id)

The exercise would be returning the sum of the costs of all autorizations made in 2016 of a client, having his `client_id` by parameter.

Comment: Could you please tag which database you are working with? This could help you better to find approrpiate answers.

Comment: Note that the sproc _creates_ a table via the `INTO sum` clause versus _returning_ a dataset.

Comment: Remove syntax errors first. DECLARE mustn't be there. don't use reserved words such as `sum` for var names. When all errors are removed, execute the proc code as script using F5